# is there a scipy.sparse.coo_matrix for higher dimensional data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray

I have some data that's saved in a coordinate format but it's 4d (time, x, y ,z + value)
I found the function [scipy.sparse.coo_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html) but this seems to only provide for 2d data.
Is there an Nd version of this function somewhere?

I could use a vectorized operation to convert my 4d coordinates to 2d and then reshape the subsequent matrix. But it seems to be that this function should exist somewhere.

Comment: It's 2d-only, like the name *matrix* implies.

Comment: I know that that's why I'm asking for an nd version...

Comment: What do want to do with it besides storing?

Comment: I don't want to store it actually, I have it stored and I simply want to quickly reconstruct the actual array. at the moment I'm just looping through the coordinates and setting the values in a blank array accordingly

Comment: Roughly what size of an array are we dealing with?  I don't what you mean by `the actual array`,  Even for 2d, `coo` stores 3 arrays and does little else.  It's usefulness comes from methods to convert to other forms,

Comment: There is a sparse n-dimensional array data structure under development at https://github.com/pydata/sparse.

Comment: pydata/sparse is exactly what I needed thanks!